# Does Bear Umbra trigger if it was attached with Sovereigns of Lost Alara?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say I have [Sovereigns of Lost Alara](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSovereigns%20of%20Lost%20Alara%5d) and attack just with [Inkwell Leviathan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bInkwell%20Leviathan%5d). Sovereigns of Lost Alara lets me search for an aura and attach it to that creature.

If I attach [Bear Umbra](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBear%20Umbra%5d) does the creature's new attack trigger trigger?

On [Ilharg, the Raze-Boar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIlharg%2c%20the%20Raze-Boar%5d) the rules say:

> Although the new creature is attacking, it was never declared as an attacking creature (for the purposes of abilities that trigger whenever a creature attacks, for example, such as those of Trusted Pegasus and Makeshift Battalion).
> (2019-05-03)

It seems as though this is a *roughly* similar case, because the creature is declared an attacker before the aura is attached, but I don't know if it's close enough or if the aura can look back at the card's previous state?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Inkwell Leviathan can't be enchanted in the first place, since it has Shroud.

Comment: @nick you fell for my trap card! Shroud prevents targeting, but Sovereigns of Lost Alara doesn't target! It's a perfectly legal move.

Comment: @nick012000 On the other hand, if it had protection from green, that would mean that it couldn't be enchanted by the aura.

Comment: why put a creature with Shroud in the question if that's not relevant to your question? If it's possible to put an aura on a creature with shroud is a different question, here it only serves to confuse.

Comment: @ikkachu it's in the deck I'm building where this interaction may happen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bear Umbra's ability triggers when the creature it enchants is declared as an attacker. That happens at the same moment Sovereigns' ability triggers, so by definition it's too late for Bear Umbra. You have more luck next turn.

> 508.1. First, the active player declares attackers. This turn-based action doesn’t use the stack. To declare attackers, the active player follows the steps below, in order. ...

> 508.2. Second, the active player gets priority. (See rule 117, “Timing and Priority.”)

> 508.2b Any abilities that triggered on attackers being declared or that triggered during the process described in rules 508.1 are put onto the stack before the active player gets priority; the order in which they triggered doesn’t matter. (See rule 603, “Handling Triggered Abilities.”)

Comment: Quoting a few select passages from CR 508.1 might not be a bad idea.

Comment: @Arthur do you have any specific ones in mind? I don't think the specifics matter much there.

Comment: @Andrew 508.1m is perhaps the most relevant, stating that triggers which trigger when creatures attack trigger here.